# Microsoft Graph - FindMeetingTimes - Unable to make request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

With most API calls in the graph API I can use the code below to retrieve an access token and then make a request to the API and it's successful:

```
$resourceUrl = 'https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default'
    $body = "client_id=CLIENTID&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&client_secret={0}&grant_type=client_credentials" -f "TOKEN"
    $auth = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/token' -Body $body -Method post -Verbose
    $accesstoken = $auth.access_token
```

However with the FindMeetingTimes API, I receive an error 400 whenever trying to make a POST request. Using the token from the graph explorer instead of mine with the same API request works fine via powershell.

I'm assuming this is due to it requiring delegated permissions, is there a way to retrieve an access token that I can call this endpoint with for this without having a user sign in beforehand?  As this is a service running in the background.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to use [resource owner password credential grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to get access token.

1. Select needed delegated permission for your application in Azure AD.
2. Grant admin consent if necessary.
3. Get token

Here is my sample:

```
$scope="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
$grant_type="password";
$username="your account id, jack@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com";
$password="your account password";
$client_id="your client id, dc****96-****-****-****-ea****6da5e7";
$client_secret="1YWt*******************21";


$body = @{
    scope  = $scope
    grant_type = $grant_type
    username = $username
    password = $password
    client_id = $client_id
    client_secret = $client_secret
}

$auth = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your_tenant_name_or_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token' -Body $body -Method post -Verbose
$auth.access_token
```

There is another approach. It is to acquire a new access token with refresh token. Here is the official documentation about it: [Refresh the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token)

Comment: @AlexP  I am glad that it helps!